# Compare LastWriteTime in an 'if' statement in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to run something like the below script every 10 minutes.

I have file A and file B. Every 10 minutes, I want to check if File A is newer than File B. If so, I want to set the LastWriteTime of file B to the current date. I believe my `if` statement is wrong... How can I fix it?

```
$a = Get-Item c:\users\testuser\desktop\test.xml | select LastWriteTime

$b = Get-Item C:\users\testuser\Desktop\test.swf | select LastWriteTime

if($a < $b)
{
    $b.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date)
}
```

I think in the above example, I'm only setting the variable $b to the current date...I want to set the LastWriteTime of the actual file to the current date.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the less than operator in the if statement and using the `Get-ChildItem` to get the file instead of the `LastWriteTime` property.

```
$a = Get-ChildItem tst1.txt  
$b = Get-ChildItem tst2.txt 

if(($a.LastWriteTime) -lt ($b.LastWriteTime))
{ 
    $b.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date) 
}
```

Learn more about operators [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx).

Comment: Thanks!...I did already try this, but i get the following... 

Cannot compare "@{LastWriteTime=7/4/2016 3:54:43 PM}" to "@{LastWriteTime=7/4/2016 2:04:11 PM}" because the objects are not the same type or the object "@{LastWriteTime=7/4/2016 3:54:43 
PM}" does not implement "IComparable".
At line:5 char:4
+ if($a -lt $b){
+    ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSObjectCompareTo

Comment: I have edited the answer. Get-Date will convert the date to the Datetime which allows you to use the comparison operators.

Comment: Still not working:

Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "@{LastWriteTime=7/4/2016 3:54:43 PM}" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "Cannot convert the "@{LastWriteTime=7/4/2016 3:54:43 
PM}" value of type "Selected.System.IO.FileInfo" to type "System.DateTime"."
At line:1 char:14
+ if((Get-Date $a) -lt (Get-Date $b)){
+              ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand

Comment: Edited once more, I assume you use US date format (MM/dd/yyyy).

Comment: Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "@{LastWriteTime=7/4/2016 3:54:43 PM}" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "Cannot convert the "@{LastWriteTime=7/4/2016 3:54:43 
PM}" value of type "Selected.System.IO.FileInfo" to type "System.DateTime"."
At line:1 char:24
+ if((Get-Date -format G $a) -lt (Get-Date -format G $b)){
+                        ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand

Comment: Modified the answer again. Please use the Get-ChildItem instead of selecting a property.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something similar to the following to change the last write time of a file:

```
$File1 = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\test1.txt"
$File2 = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\test2.txt"

#System.IO is a namespace of the file class in .NET and GetLastWriteTime/SetLastWriteTime are methods of this class.
if ([System.IO.File]::GetLastWriteTime($File1) -lt [System.IO.File]::GetLastWriteTime($File2))
    {
        Write-Output  "File1 LastWriteTime is less than File2, Setting LastWriteTime on File2."
            ([System.IO.File]::SetLastWriteTime($File2,(Get-Date)))
    }
ELSE
    {
        Write-Output "File1 LastWriteTime is not less than File2 LastWriteTime."
    }
```

More information on the Namespace, .NET class, and associated methods used in the above code can be found [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx).

Hope this helps!

Comment: This might work for some but its not very Powershell like... :) And it is alooooooot of typing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It worked for me in PowerShell 5.

In order to change the date of LastWriteTime, you have to write to file again, for example,

```
$a = Get-Item fileA.txt
$b = Get-Item fileB.txt

if(($a.LastWriteTime) -lt ($b.LastWriteTime))
{
    fileB.txt | add-content -Value ''
}
```